# Private properties to subclass

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, oop

I have a class B that inherits from Class A.
I want to declare some properties in class A and import some classes in it however i dont want to expose these properties or classes to the user of Class b

In  simple words i want to find a way to declare  properties that can be used only by it subclass and not those that import it sub class

Comment: not possible....you can only make private properties using class extenstions, but they can be accessed as well

Comment: On the contrary, this is possible, and good practice. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible, and in fact good practice.

In A.h, you should import only what is absolutely necessary, such as headers containing protocols you must adhere to publicly. Any other classes needed should be pre-defined with `@class` and `@protocol`. Declare any properties you can read-only.

```
@class SomeObject

@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) SomeObject *object;
@end
```

In A.m, you should import any headers you need privately. Also, implement a category extension and redeclare any read-only properties as readwrite.

```
#import "SomeObject.h"

@interface ClassA ()
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *id;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) SomeObject *object;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *entirelyPrivate;
@end

@implementation A
. . . . etc
```

If you'd like to make these values available to a subclass, but not to other classes, you can put them in a category. This is done by several classes in the Apple frameworks, as well.

Eg, create a file `ClassA+Subclass.h` and include:

```
@interface ClassA (SubclassOnly)
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *id;
@end
```

Then simply import that in the *implementation* of the subclass that needs 'protected' access.

Comment: You can use the same technique, but putting some of it in an additional file, to allow subclasses access to private values. Let me know if you'd like me to expand.

Comment: This isn't what the user asked. You are still exposing those properties to anything that imports `ClassA` as well as properties that subclass it. You've just made them readonly. `Anoop Vaidya` is correct it isn't possible.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this is incorrect. For example, the `entirelyPrivate` NSString is, as the user asked, not exposed to classes that subclass `ClassA`.

The above provides examples of both partially exposed and entirely private properties. The same pattern can be continued to make properties or imports entirely private as the OP wishes.

Comment: What they are after is an access modifier in objective-c that is equivalent to javas protected which there is none. In objective-c there are only 2 `public` and `private` there is no why to make an property entirely accessible to only the subclasses and not classes that import it. It's either private to that one class so no subclasses or class that imports it can access it OR it is public in which case any class that imports or subclasses it has access to it.

Comment: All you are doing in your code here is make one property (`entirelyPrivate`) as the name suggests completely private and just making it so anything that imports or subclasses this class can only read `id` and `object` they are still visible everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm not entirely sure you're right, since they ask "I have a class B that inherits from Class A. I want to declare some properties in class A and import some classes in it however i dont want to expose these properties or classes to the user of Class b". But, you're correct that this is impossible to accomplish at the runtime level, since Objective-C is dynamically bound. However, the technique I mention in my first comment allows the same effect at compile time. I've expanded my answer to include an example of that technique.

Comment: @tooluser Yes I was looking for something like protected in java

Comment: @ArpitKohli if you find the above explanation about the objective c runtime and how to implement an analogous system helps you, would you please 'accept' the answer? It's considered bad practice on SO to ask questions and not accept answers.